# Unable to setup Struts 2 environment

Tags: struts2

I'm getting this error message in the index.jsp file

**Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic"**

How do I rectify it?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Make sure you included the tag `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>` in your index.jsp file and `struts-tags.tld` is present in your `WEB-INF/classes` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer this Hello World Application tutorial link](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hello-world-example-1.html), you can compare your code with this sample codes and solve your issue.

Jar files which all are required are also available there in that link ( Except MySQL connector).